# Break out of a while loop and into another c#

Tags: c#, while-loop, visual-studio-2015, do-while

I'm a little stuck with my while loops. Both parts of the code work perfectly on their own, however, I can't seem to make both of the while loops work. Would appreciate any help at all:

```
using System;
namespace week5task3 {
    class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            double PriceEvery1 = 5;
            double PriceEvery2 = 4;
            double PriceEvery3 = 2.5;
            double Quantity = 10;
            int UserCounter = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nWidget Price Chart\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Quantity of Widgets\t\tPrice");

            while (UserCounter <= 100) {
                double Price1 = PriceEvery1 * Quantity;
                double Price2 = PriceEvery2 * Quantity;
                double Price3 = PriceEvery3 * Quantity;

                if (Quantity <= 50) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t\t\t{1:C}", Quantity, Price1);
                }

                if (Quantity >= 51 && Quantity <= 80) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t\t\t{1:C}", Quantity, Price2);
                }

                if (Quantity >= 81 && Quantity <= 100) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t\t\t{1:C}", Quantity, Price3);
                }
                Quantity += 10;
            }

            while (UserCounter >= 0) {
                try {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of widgets you would like to purchase or press q to quit");
                    string temp = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (temp == "q") break;
                    if (temp == "Q") break;

                    int.TryParse(temp, out UserCounter);

                    double UserPrice;

                    if (UserCounter <= 50) {
                        UserPrice = UserCounter * 5;
                        Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}", UserPrice);
                    }

                    if (UserCounter >= 51 && UserCounter <= 80) {
                        UserPrice = UserCounter * 4;
                        Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}", UserPrice);
                    }

                    if (UserCounter > 80) {
                        UserPrice = UserCounter * 2.5;
                        Console.WriteLine("The price is {0:C}", UserPrice);
                    }


                } catch (Exception) {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value. Please enter a number or press q to quit");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are never incrementing `UserCounter` or breaking out of the first loop so it will never end.

Comment: thanks for your response! I've attempted both break; and continue;, but neither have been successful...

Comment: Maybe you meant `while (Quantity <= 100)`? Keep in mind I have no idea what you actually want to happen so you will need to explain what your application is supposed to do.

Comment: This first While Loop display a price list, and the second While is to calculate the price of widgets to the customer.. hope that makes some sense...       What I am hoping to achieve is:   To be able to run both of the While loops.

Comment: Thanks Juan C. for cleaning up my messy code. :)

Comment: So does `while (Quantity <= 100)` for the first loop fix it?

Comment: Yes! that fixed it  Thank you so much Cyral.  Very much appreciated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `while (Quantity <= 100)` instead of `UserCounter <= 100`. This will exit the loop after 10 iterations of printing the price.